# Problem with relative coordinates within \draw command

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, coordinates

I've got a problem with the following code. I'm trying to draw a circuit using [`circuitikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz). However, the current source should be shifted by 1 unit in the x-direction, so that it is placed parallel to the first inductor of the transformer. I figured it should work with this relative coordinate positioning but there seems to be a problem.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0)
            node[transformer core, yscale=1.25] (T) {};
            \draw (T.A2)+(-1,0)
            to [sI] (T.A1)+(-1,0);              
            \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{My first circuit.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use something like

```
\draw (T.A2) -- +(-1,0)
            to [sI] ($(T.A1)+(-1,0)$) -- (T.A1);
```

Start with `T.A2`, move the pen to left by 1 unit, then draw the current source up to the point `($(T.A1)+(-1,0)$)` (this needs `calc` library) and then connect to `T.A1`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0)
            node[transformer core, yscale=1.25] (T) {};
            \draw (T.A2) -- +(-1,0)
            to [sI] ($(T.A1)+(-1,0)$) -- (T.A1);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-circ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(4.5,4)
  \pnodes(0.5,0){A}(0.5,4){B}(2.5,4){C}(4.5,4){D}(4.5,0){E}(2.5,0){F}
  \transformer(C)(F)(D)(E){}
  \wire(A)(F)
  \vac(A)(B){}
  \wire(B)(C)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]